# iTerm: Can I Get Transparency in Full Screen Mode

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, iterm

Can I get transparency in full screen mode in iTerm?

Answer (score 17):

In Preferences -> General tab, uncheck **Native full screen windows**.

[image: Uncheck **Native fullscreen windows**]

Comment: Also make sure "Disable transparency for fullscreen windows by default" in the Appearance tab. (And also exit and re enter full sreen, it doesn't do apply this to current full screen windows)

Comment: Thank you for your post.

Comment: I think @Bella's comment should be added to the answer for completeness! Seems important enough to have been what did it for me.

Answer (score 15):

Uncheck `Lion-style fullscreen windows` in *Preferences* -> *General* tab.

Works for *iTerm2 Build 2.1.1* on *OSX 10.9.5*.

Comment: This has been renamed to `Native full screen windows` in iTerm2 3.0.3

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: thank you for your post.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you change transparency in a full-screen iTerm window, it only takes affect when you leave full screen. The idea of the full screen mode is to let you focus on the work at hand in a single terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble getting the *Native Full screen windows* and *Disable transparency for full screen windows* changes (recommended in the accepted answer) to work.

However, the iTerm *View* menu now has a *Use Transparency* (mapped to <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>) and selecting that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

On Tiger, when I have iTerm open full screen and I open a new tab, the new tab is transparent--so it's possible. It reverts back to opaque if you minimize and re-full screen it, though. However, I agree with jtimberman; I find it annoying to have a full-screen transparent window.

Answer (score -1):

There's a solution but it's a bit of a hack :

- Try using [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) to setup the transparency of the window.

Comment: -1 Dead link to what is effectively a link-only answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is coming before long. Star this bug to know when it's fixed: http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=276

Comment: -1 Dead link to what is effectively a link-only answer.